# Cordova's distro files (jar) are not generated

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to start a simple Cordova 3.0.0 project under Windows. Development environment (including Java, Eclipse, Ant, Android SDK) does exist and has been already used for numerous native apps.

I was able to create a "hello" project using:

```
>create hellocordova com.example.hellocordova "HelloWorldCordova"
Creating new android project...
Building jar and js files...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Creating appinfo.jar...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```

It worked ok, though there are no distro files in the project.

After that I've tried to build Cordova's distro files using `update`:

```
>update hellocordova
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building jar and js files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
```

It does not show any errors, but the files `cordova-3.0.0.jar` and `cordova-3.0.0.js` are missing in respective folders (`libs` and `assets/www`) where they should appear.

The problem could possibly be related to API Level (though I'm not sure how). `check_reqs` reports:

```
Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK).
```

Yes, I have 4.1 as the highest API level at the moment and would like to keep it so. But I don't see in Cordova scripts any indication that the level must be exactly 17, except for the `check_reqs` itself, which seems not involved in building process.

I'd appreciate suggestions how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I missed the step which does actually build the jar-file:

```
ant jar
```

for Cordova framework project. I didn't see this in the documentation.

After further investigation I found that `create` and `update` executes this command inside:

```
exec('ant.bat -f \"'+ ROOT +'\\framework\\build.xml\" jar');
```

The problem is that the command executes well manually, that is it produces the jar, but it silently fails to produce it when invoked inside `create` or `update`. For clarity I outputted the resulting command line from `update`, then copy & paste it and run in shell in the same directory. This works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you for the last couple of hours and problem came (silently as you said :D) from ant. My version of ant was not recent enough (1.7 instead of 1.8).

After updating it seems to work great (jar generated in correct file) even automatically (read inside the phonegap command scripts like run android).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but i was missing
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin
And the Path  to Java.
the -d ( i think debug ) will give you more information.
create -d hellocordova com.example.hellocordova "HelloWorldCordova"

this was on Cordova 3.0.9 and adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729.
Als do not forget to update the SDK so the you have the corect Android platforms.